# Radial distribution function of particles in water at room temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, interactions, distance

I am trying to figure out some experimental effects I'm seeing, and I hypothesize that what I'm seeing is due to particles interacting with each other (which I neglected, hoping that I didn't need to figure out HOW they interact with each other ;)). To evaluate whether this might be causing my results, I am going to need some way of figuring out how far the particles are apart, and how many there are.

I have molecules dissolved in water, at room temperature. I can't imagine that no one has found a nice, ready-made description of this. I haven't found it, and am probably using the wrong search terms or looking in the wrong places. Or I'm not understanding the things I find.

I think I need a radial distribution function. Many websites refer to this, e.g. [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Molecular_Simulation/Radial_Distribution_Functions) or [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biological_Chemistry/Concepts_in_Biophysical_Chemistry_(Tokmakoff)/01%3A_Water_and_Aqueous_Solutions/01%3A_Fluids/1.02%3A_Radial_Distribution_Function). Thing is, there is always some term describing the number density of particles in the solvation shell, and the shells around it. I do not know how to find/calculate it.

The questions I'm trying to answer:

1. Given some concentration of molecule A in water, what would be the distribution of number of water molecules as a function of distance to any molecule A?
2. Same situation as 1, but now I would like to find the distribution of number of A as a function of distance to any molecule A.
3. If I add molecule B to the mixture, I would also like to know number of B as a function of distance to molecule A.

I'm not quite sure if question 3 is essentially the same as question 2, or if this severely complicates things.

As a first step, I'm perfectly happy to use some severely simplified model, e.g. assuming hard spheres. That would probably already help me out, to see if my line of thought is viable or not. If something is available specifically for aqueous solutions, that would of course be fantastic.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and help out if you can.